# How can I make the Visio Online API 1.1 demo work properly?

Tags: office-js

There is a Visio Online API demo on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/VisioJs_1.1_Openspec/reference/visio/visio-javascript-reference-overview.md .

I just can't make it work properly. Here are my steps:

1. Change the Office365 Release Preference to "First release for everyone" to make sure Visio Onlie Preview is activated. https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/companyprofile . Turn on the "Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites" option on https://***-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/TenantSettings.aspx. These may need several hours to take effect.
2. I create a site at Sharepoint Online with the template "Developer Site". http://***.sharepoint.com/sites/dev.
3. Upload a visio document to the Documents folder of the site. Now I can view it on url : https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={5e7cbe8e-9063-499c-b8d6-b5bad3eaddab}&action=interactivepreview
4. Create a Web Part page "visio.aspx" with layout "Full Page,Vertical" and save it to "Site Pages".
5. Add a Web Part "Media and Content\Script Editor" to the page. Click the "Edit Snippet" and paste the demo code in "Get Started" section on url https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/VisioJs_1.1_Openspec/reference/visio/visio-javascript-reference-overview.md . Click "Insert" and then Click "Stop Edit" to save changes.
6. Now I can view the demo page on url: https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/visio.aspx .
7. Enter the visio document address to the input box. "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={5e7cbe8e-9063-499c-b8d6-b5bad3eaddab}&action=interactivepreview" and click "InitEmbeddedFrame" button to load the visio content.
8. The Visio file is indeed shown later. But I get a error message "Initilization is failed :-(" later in the text field and the SelectedShapeText button can't work with only "Error:" message came out.

What's wrong with my steps? Does anyone make the demo work properly ever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps that you have taken are correct.
The demo is not working because the Visio Online APIs are not released yet.

For now, you can give feedback related to signatures of the API.
The APIs Preview will be coming out soon and then you will be able to try out the demo.